# Kubernetes - kubernetes delete by GCP

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Recently my GCP kubernetes service be delete and re-create by GCP system, but i no idel what' happen. The kubernetes service is running so long time, and this event is first time.Hope someone can help me to know what's happen?
Error message like below :
Kubernetes apiservice request delete gke-stage-service.......
Kubernetes apiservice request delete kube-system:fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-4ff9m ....
Kubernetes apiservice request delete kube-system : kube-proxy-gke....
Kubernetes apiservice request patch kube-system:kube-dns.......
Kubernetes apiservice request create node-csr-P08-mjFgERo....

Comment: I had some questions before going forward to suspect the issue:

1.Can you please provide which kubernetes version currently working on ?

Comment: 2) When did this issue started as it can be related to on-going technical issue with [Kernel Panic](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/release-notes) in some of the GKE versions ?